# Confusion over C++ pointer and reference topic

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What is the difference between the following parameter passing mechanisms in C++?

```
void foo(int &x) 
void foo(int *x)
void foo(int **x)
void foo(int *&x)
```

I'd like to know in which case the parameter is being passed by value or passed by reference.

Comment: No, I am learning C++, but it looks messy, and I am just confused.

Comment: Parameters are passed by reference if there is a `&` symbol. Otherwise they are passed by value (the pointers are passed by value).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void foo(int &x)
```

passes a reference to an integer.  This is an input/output parameter and can be used like a regular integer in the function.  Value gets passed back to the caller.

---

```
void food(int *x)
```

passes a pointer to an integer.  This is an input/output parameter but it's used like a pointer and has to be dereferenced (e.g. `*x = 100;`).  You also need to check that it's not null.

---

```
void foo(int **x)
```

passes a pointer to a pointer to an integer.  This is an input/output parameter of type integer pointer.  Use this if you want to change the value of an integer point (e.g. `*x = &m_myInt;`).

---

```
void foo(int *&x)
```

passes a reference to a pointer to an integer.  Like above but no need to dereference the pointer variable (e.g. `x = &m_myInt;`).

---

Hope that makes sense. I would recommend using typedefs to simplify the use of pointers and reference symbols.

Comment: The last one is a pointer to a reference, it would still need to be dereferenciated. A reference to a pointer would be declared like `void foo(int &*x)`

Comment: @Vargas: A reference to a pointer is 'int *&x' and not 'int &*x'. What you mentioned is 'pointer to reference'. By the way, C++ does not allow pointer to reference.

Comment: @Chubsdad +1; @Vargas, read from right to left ("x is a reference to a pointer to an int")

Answer (score 1):

Just adding: I think your spacing is misleading. Maybe things get a bit clearer if you change it.

The *, &, ** and so on is part of the type, so keep it with the type:

```
void foo(int& x) 
void foo(int* x)
void foo(int** x)
void foo(int*& x)
```

int& is an reference to an int, int* is a pointer to an int, int** is a pointer to an pointer to an int, and so on.
You still need to read the types from right to left - int*& being a reference to an pointer to an int. But that's consistent.

I think this is easier to read and represents better what is meant.